# Sensor manager is moving the ball too fast

Tags: android, bitmap, sensors

i am moving a bitmap ball on canvas while sensors are changed but the problem is that it is moving ball too quickly even when phone is stable it is moving it shakes at one same place even when ball phone is stable.
how would i decrease the speed of sensor to recognize the movement of device it gives even a slight change in the phone so can any one help me it would be a great help
here is my code

```
public class Can extends SurfaceView implements Runnable,
        SensorEventListener {


    public Can(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context);

        ourHolder = getHolder();
        sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        if (sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size() != 0) {
            Sensor s = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "registered", 500).show();
            sm.registerListener(this, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        }
        ball = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
    }

    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        isRunning = true;
        ourThread = new Thread(this);
        ourThread.start();
        w.acquire();
    }

    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        isRunning = false;
        while (true) {
            try {
                ourThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        ourThread = null;
        w.release();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (isRunning) {
            if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                continue;
            }
            Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            Rect red = new Rect(0, canvas.getHeight() / 2,canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            Paint Pred = new Paint();
            Pred.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawRect(red, Pred);
            ballY = ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - (ball.getHeight() / 2))+ sensorY*70  ;
            ballX = ((canvas.getWidth() / 2) - (ball.getWidth() / 2))+ sensorX*70 ;
            if(ballX>(canvas.getWidth()-ball.getWidth())){
                ballX=canvas.getWidth()-ball.getWidth();
            }
            if(ballX<0){
                ballX=0;
            }
            if(ballY<0){
                ballY=0;
            }
            if(ballY>(canvas.getHeight()-ball.getHeight())){
                ballY=canvas.getHeight()-ball.getHeight();
            }
            canvas.drawBitmap(ball, ballX, ballY, null);
            Paint Pblack = new Paint();
            Pblack.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            Paint Pwhite = new Paint();
            Pwhite.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2, 0, ball.getWidth(), Pblack);
            canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2,canvas.getHeight(),ball.getWidth(), Pwhite);
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sensorY = event.values[0];
        sensorX = event.values[1];
        try {
            Thread.sleep(16);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Fix 1

**Reduce gain**
Currently you have too much sensitivity set for your sensor value.

```
ballY = ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - (ball.getHeight() / 2))+ sensorY*70  ;
ballX = ((canvas.getWidth() / 2) - (ball.getWidth() / 2))+ sensorX*70 ;
```

Here sensitivity is 70 which should be reduced to make it more stable. The optimum value should be determined by using extreme values of the data. Try increasing it slowly from 1.

---

### Fix 2

**Filter for stability**
The accelerometer data usually fluctuates a lot. It might be a good idea to stabilize it using a low pass filter.

When you get new sensor data,

```
// gain has some value between 0 and 1. For start, try gain = 0.5 
sensorX = gain * newSensorXValue + (1 - gain) * sensorX;
```

Similarly for Y axis.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.